# after applying authentication flow in react navigation 6 this error is appearing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

This is my ShopNavigator.js as you see there is authentication flow i have applied but it is showing this error even the screen name is corret. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue before it is switchNavigator in reactNavigation 6.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function ShopNavigator() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="StartUp" drawerContent={props => {
                return (
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 5 }}>
                        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                            <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: "always", horizontal: "never", }}>
                                <DrawerItemList {...props} />
                                <DrawerItem {...props}
                                    label="logout"
                                    color="red"
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        dispatch(authActions.logout());
                                        props.navigation.navigate("AuthScreen")
                                    }}
                                />
                            </SafeAreaView>
                        </DrawerContentScrollView>
                    </View>
                )
            }}
            >
                {authActions.AUTHENTICATE ? (
                    <Stack.Group>
                        <Stack.Screen name="StartUp" component={StartupScreen}
                            options={{
                                drawerItemStyle: { height: 0 }
                            }} />
                        <Drawer.Screen name="AuthScreen" component={AuthScreen}
                            options={{
                                drawerItemStyle: { height: 0 }
                            }} />
                    </Stack.Group>
                ) : (

                    <Stack.Group>
                        <Drawer.Screen name="ProductsOverviewScreen" component={ProductOverviewScreen}
                            options={{
                                title: "Home",
                                drawerIcon: drawerConfig => (
                                    <Ionicons name="md-home"
                                        size={23}
                                        color="green" />
                                ),
                            }}
                        />
                        )}
 </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
)};
```

[image: This error it is showing even the screen name is Correct]